# What is the difference between the "access" and "user-access" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are questions tagged [access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access), and questions tagged [user-access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-access); as far as I know, the term access is always used to refer to user access.

Is there any reason to have both the tags?

**Update**: As there are [node-access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node-access) and [user-access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-access), I don't see any reason to have [access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access), except when it means "file access"; in that case, we should probably have [file-access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-access) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node access and User access are subtly different, and even within Node access there are two approaches, `hook_node_access()` and Node Grants. That said, they are closely related, with another assenting opinion I can merge them.

Comment: If [tag:access] is referring to node access, then it could be better to rename it [tag:node-access], if the tag doesn't exist already.